# avr-gcc woes: ignores permanent variable/register binding. Why?

Tags: c, avr-gcc

Still struggling with AVR assembly. This time `avr-gcc` seems to completely ignore my directive to [permanently bind a local variable to a register](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/AVRLibcReferenceManual/FAQ_1faq_regbind.html). Here's an example — this is of course just an illustration, not the final code:

```
// C code:
ISR(USART1_RX_vect)
{
    register uint8_t c asm("r3") = UDR1;
    tty1::buffer[tty1::ptr.head] = c;
}

// Generated assembly:
000000d8 <__vector_20>:
  d8:   1f 92           push    r1
  da:   0f 92           push    r0
  dc:   0f b6           in      r0, SREG        ; 63
  de:   0f 92           push    r0
  e0:   11 24           eor     r1, r1
  e2:   8f 93           push    r24
  e4:   ef 93           push    r30
  e6:   ff 93           push    r31
  e8:   80 91 73 00     lds     r24, UDR1       ; 0x800073 <__EEPROM_REGION_LENGTH__+0x7f0073>
  ec:   e0 91 01 01     lds     r30, 0x0101     ; 0x800101 <tty<drv::uart1>::ptr>
  f0:   e2 95           swap    r30
  f2:   ef 70           andi    r30, 0x0F       ; 15
  f4:   f0 e0           ldi     r31, 0x00       ; 0
  f6:   ee 5f           subi    r30, 0xFE       ; 254
  f8:   fe 4f           sbci    r31, 0xFE       ; 254
  fa:   80 83           st      Z, r24
  fc:   ff 91           pop     r31
  fe:   ef 91           pop     r30
 100:   8f 91           pop     r24
 102:   0f 90           pop     r0
 104:   0f be           out     SREG, r0        ; 63
 106:   0f 90           pop     r0
 108:   1f 90           pop     r1
 10a:   18 95           reti
```

- Give me `r3`, please.

- Sure thing! here's `r24`.

I can ask any register between `r2` and `r7` that compiler just takes whatever it wants! And it has nothing to do with `UDR1`, it does that with whatever I assign `c`. What's the point of that directive if it does nothing at all? How am I supposed to control the register the compiler selects?

To the question «*Why the heck am I wanting to assign variable to a register?*» I reply «*Because the generated code is sub-optimal for an interrupt and I want a fine control over the generated assembly.*» So far it's been a trouble for me.

Still using `avr-gcc` version 7.1.0...

Comment: try to make `c` global, instead of ISR-local.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Can't just *local* variables be assigned to registers? What about [the documentation](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/AVRLibcReferenceManual/inline_asm_1c_names_in_asm.html)? I have no need (nor interest) for global variables permanently assigned to registers, in fact.

Comment: You seem to have missed the fact that the compiler wants to preserve the values of `r2` thru `r7` without having to push them onto the stack. So choose a register that the compiler *will* let you have, like `r24` and get on with your life.

Comment: I think @user3386109 has a point. What the documentation possibly wanted to say was "in the context of functions, not ISRs, you can use r2 to r7 freely". But, AVR-gcc is not known for being bug free. Try `register uint8_t c asm("r3"); c = UDR1;` instead, or, really, write assembly to save `r3` (to stack or to another register), do your magic, and then restore r3. Not like you'd be saving anything by letting your compiler do that under the hood.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I think I'm going to write everything by hand, like you suggested. Seems the only way, not even `asm()` statements give enough control upon input/output variables and register selection. BTW I already tried assigning variable `c` on a second line. Moving the code to a function doesn't help either. *sigh*

Comment: @Nasha that might be for a purpose! Maybe `r3` really shouldn't be used in an ISR! I don't know!

Comment: @MarcusMüller If you add the required `push`/`pop` instructions, you can use whatever register you like.

Comment: @Nasha unless you get into hell because R3 is used in a higher-priority ISR, or so

Comment: @MarcusMüller ISR's are not supposed to use registers without pushing them onto the stack first. Moreover I'm the only one to write the code and I check everything systematically so that hypothetical situation is highly unlikely. Or I'm checking the code while I'm drunk. Which is also equally unlikely.

Comment: :D yeah, if you check! Notice that I'd really have to look into what the ABI states as conventions on what interrupts to stash onto the stack and which not, but in principle, you're very right, r3 shouldn't be any special

Comment: Note that I don't care whether it's r3 or whatever. I just want the compiler to do what I tell it, period. Could be r69 for as far as I care...

Comment: Yup, that is a flaw in `gcc` in general. If it sees something it doesn't agree with, it should generate a diagnostic and stop. But it typically just does what it wants, and doesn't give any feedback whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the declaration from the Interrupt Service Routine (ISR) to the global scope. GCC allows global and local permanent bindings. Yours is in the ISR scope, which is but useless in your case.

I will try my best to give a more detailed explanation.

### Local scope

1. Register from the binding stops to be a register, and it is treated as the storage location.
2. The same optimisation rules apply as to any other automatic variables.
3. The ISR has to restore all of the registers (except those bound in the global scope) - so no side effects possible - even if registers are bound in the local scope.

See the code:
https://godbolt.org/g/HsjvCa and https://godbolt.org/g/ZGjvRE with optimisations on.

Local bindings do not change any general register use rules.

If you bind registers - you can't call any functions compiled without header files with register bindings (global scope). In the local scope call to any function invalidates the local bindings.

Comment: You do not understand what this binding is. I will explain it more detail in my answer soon.

Comment: I'm also considering that as an option, given how difficult it's been to get it all so far...

Comment: I may be missing something but I still don't understand this kind of implementation (i.e. GCC and its assembly "interface"), that's too convoluted for me. It is not related to your explanation, you've done your best to illustrate it and I thank you very much for that. Maybe my understanding is limited, I dunno. I'll do with what I've understood anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> avr-gcc seems to completely ignore my directive to permanently bind a local variable to a register.

That's correct:

### Local Register Variables

According to the GCC documentation for [local register variables](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html), **the only supported use of local register variables is as operands of inline assembly**:

> The only supported use for this feature is to specify registers for input and output operands when calling Extended asm

As you just have a definition of a local reg variable but no inline assembly, there's no need to allocate `c` to R3. And even if avr-gcc would use R3, it would have to push / pop it so you wouldn't gain anything.

### Global Register Variables

Using a global register variable might not do what you expect, either.  Take for example

```
char a, b;
register char r3 asm ("r3");

void func (void)
{
    r3 = a;
    b = r3;
}
```

which will be compiled to (tested with avr-gcc -Os with v5, v8, v11, v13):

```
func:
    lds r24,a
    mov r3,r24
    sts b,r24
    ret
```

Apart from that, global register variables come with their own caveats:

- Such variables are supposed to be *global*, i.e. the compiler must not use them for register allocation (which is the reason for the above code by the way).  This implies that the **global reg definition must be present in each compilation unit, even in those that do not use it explicitly.**  Alternatively, one can turn R3 into a fixed register be means of command line option `-ffixed-3` or `-ffixed-r3`.
- You actually do not have control over the options used for each compilation unit, in particular libraries like libgcc, AVR-LibC or 3rd party libraries might use R3.
- Many of the modules in AVR-LibC are written in assembly, so even compiling them with `-ffixed-*` would not have an effect on R3 usage. None of the libgcc assembly functions are using R2...R9 though, but there are also C functions in libgcc.

### Conclusion

Register variables won't bring the expected code, but they will introduce unexpected caveats and need extra attention.

> I want a fine control over the generated assembly

The goto technique to actually have *fine control* is writing the ISR in assembly, or at least to write bits of it in inline assembly.  This is indicated anyways when you need control over each cycle in an ISR.

You might also consider avr-gcc v8 because it implements optimized ISR prologues and epilogues as of [PR81268](https://gcc.gnu.org/PR81268) — but no avr-gcc v9...v13 due to [PR90706](https://gcc.gnu.org/PR90706).

Take for example the following code with avr-gcc v8 on ATmega16 -Os:

```c
unsigned char c, x, a[10];

__attribute__((signal))
void __vector1 (void)
{
    a[x] = c;
}
```

On older than v8 (or with attribute `no_gccisr`), the outcome is:

```
00000000 <__vector1>:
   0:   1f 92           push    r1
   2:   0f 92           push    r0
   4:   0f b6           in  r0, 0x3f    ; SREG
   6:   0f 92           push    r0
   8:   11 24           eor r1, r1
   a:   8f 93           push    r24
   c:   ef 93           push    r30
   e:   ff 93           push    r31
  ...            6 instructions in function body
  20:   ff 91           pop r31
  22:   ef 91           pop r30
  24:   8f 91           pop r24
  26:   0f 90           pop r0
  28:   0f be           out 0x3f, r0    ; SREG
  2a:   0f 90           pop r0
  2c:   1f 90           pop r1
  2e:   18 95           reti
```

Without `reti`, prologue + epilogue is 15 instructions and 27 ticks, whereas the fully optimized version takes 10 instructions and 18 ticks:

```
00000000 <__vector1>:
   0:   8f 93           push    r24
   2:   8f b7           in  r24, 0x3f   ; SREG
   4:   8f 93           push    r24
   6:   ef 93           push    r30
   8:   ff 93           push    r31
  ...            6 instructions in function body
  1a:   ff 91           pop r31
  1c:   ef 91           pop r30
  1e:   8f 91           pop r24
  20:   8f bf           out 0x3f, r24   ; SREG
  22:   8f 91           pop r24
  24:   18 95           reti
```